# How can I change the MPS format in Linear Programming samples of Mathematica?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to play with some linear programming examples of *Mathematica* as `ExampleData[{"LinearProgramming", "blend"}, "Equations"]`. It gives me the MPS format of the samples. How can I change them?

Comment: You've seen [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationLinearProgramming.html#9813130)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do is to import in the `ConstraintMatrix` form.

```
 Import["ExampleData/afiro.mps", "ConstraintMatrix"]
```

This gives a `SparseArray` object, which can be turned back into a regular matrix format using `Normal`. Some other possible manipulations of the MPS data are discussed [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/MPS.html).

Comment: Could you please show me how I can use the `Normal` and after changing it how having new `SparseArray` again?

Comment: After applying `Normal` it is a matrix of values and you can do anything with it you desire. If you name it (say `m`) then you can get back to sparse form by `SparseArray[m]`.